# do post to two forms in one click javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function Add () {

    document.getElementById("newCart.php").submit();
    document.getElementById("PreviousCarts.php").submit();
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="myform" Id="myform" action="POST" method ="POST"  data-ajax="false">
<div class="main-content-wrapper"> 
<div class="image box-right" style="text-align: center"><img src="pic/shoping cart.jpg" border="0" width="150" height="150" 
                    title="go to a new cart!" onclick="if (validateEmail()) { Add ();} else {return false;}">
<span class="style1"><strong><br>New Shop Cart</strong></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; </div>
<div class="image box-left" style="text-align: center"><img src="pic/page_accept .png" border="0" width="150" height="150" 
                    title="go to a your old shopping bag!" onclick="if (validateEmail()) { Add ();} else {return false;}">
<span class="style1"><strong><br>your Previous shopping carts</strong></span></div>
```

We want to do post or to form name `newcart` or to form `previouscart`.
We tried this code but it does not work.
Do you have recommendation?

Comment: Send it two one PHP file, that includes the two PHP files, or use AJAX. if it comes to the first .submit() the execution of the script ceases, so only the first will be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as `document.getElementById("newCart.php").submit();`  executes the browsers runs out to fetch the next page.You can't post two forms from one page(without iframe).

However you can put one `hidden field` in one of the form and set its values with `PreviousCarts`/`newCart` content and then post this form.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that one of the PHP file is just doing some background process and one display information, you can first send the form via generated frame to the background process, wait a short time and submit to the main page:

```
function Add () {
    var oForm = document.getElementById("myform");

    //create hidden frame:
    var oFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
    oFrame.id = "MyHiddenFrame";
    oFrame.name = "MyHiddenFrame";
    oFrame.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(oFrame);

    //submit to first page via hidden frame:
    oForm.target = "MyHiddenFrame";
    oForm.action = "PreviousCarts.php";
    oForm.submit();

    //submit to second page:
    oForm.target = "";
    oForm.action = "newCart.php";
    oForm.submit();
}
```

This is not best practice, just in case for some reason you can't do that server side.